# in java what does the @ symbol mean?

Tags: java, symbols

I know what it means in a comment for documentation purposes, but outside of that what does it mean? (I would normally just google this but every non letter symbol shows up in results)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24221/java-annotations

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19551022/the-symbol-in-java

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a nice URL like "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074/asp-mvc"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227348/how-to-get-a-nice-url-like-http-stackoverflow-com-questions-1074-asp-mvc)

Comment: You can search in google with `java At` not `java @`

Comment: [What does the @ sign means in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2971521/6521116)

Comment: It means BAD language design.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

The `@` symbol denotes a Java Annotation. What a Java annotation does, is that it adds a special attribute to the variable, method, class, interface, or other language elements. (This can be configured when you declare the annotation) When you add an annotation to something, other parts of the program can check whether something has an annotation or not. It then can use this information to do whatever stuff they need.

Let me give you some examples:

### The `@Override` annotation

```
public class SuperClass {
    public void someInterestingMethod() {
        System.out.println("Superclass!");
    }
}

public class DerivedClass extends SuperClass {
    public void someInterestngMethod() {
        System.out.println("Derived class!");
    }
}
```

And when you do this:

```
SuperClass sc = new DerivedClass();
sc.someInterestingMethod();
```

The `someInterestingMethod()` call should be dynamically dispatched, and print `"Derived class!"`, right? Well the derived class' method was actually misspelled, so `DerivedClass` got its own separate method called `someInterestngMethod()`, totally unrelated to the superclass' `someInterestingMethod()`. As such, `someInterestingMethod()` is no longer overridden, and the superclass' implementation is invoked.

The `@Override` keyword is intended to help with this. It signals your intent to the compiler, that you would like the annotated method to be an overload of one of the ancestor class' methods. If it's not (such as in this typo case, or if the `SuperClass` API changed and renamed the method), the will fail your compilation, to alert your attention to the broken override.

### The `@SuppressWarnings` Annotation

Here is a method:

```
public void someMethod() {
    int i;
}
```

There will be a compiler warning saying that `i` is never used. So you can add the `@SuppressWarnings` to the method to *suppress* the warning:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public void someMethod() {
    int i;
}
```

Note that there is a parameter to the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation. Some annotations have parameters and you can look for the them in the javadoc. But for those that don't have parameters you don't need to add `()` like a method.

You can also declare your own annotations and use reflection to check for them. The above 2 annotations will be checked by the compiler.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I don't know why I forgot to fixe this for such a long time, but someone downvoting this again has made be remember that I had posted this particular answer half a decade ago... Now it's fixed :)

Comment: hey, thanks for addressing this. Would you mind if I suggested the edit? I have an example in mind that would better reflect the utility of `@Override`

Comment: Oh, my edits show up immediately without approval :| Curse of high reputation haha. Could you let me know what you think? Feel free to tweak/revert if you feel that's appropriate https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31822268/revisions

Comment: Glad I could help :) Deleted my now-irrelevant comment

Answer (score 15):

The @ sign is used to specify Java Annotation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation

There are built-in Java Annotation and user defined Custom Annotation.

Annotations are used in various ways, such as suppress warning, associate method to URI (Servlet), associate variables to resource (JNDI) etc

Answer (score 7):

The @ symbol is used for [annotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation).  In my experience, the most common annotation is `@Override`, which indicates that a method is declared in a superclass.  Other common annotations are `@Deprecated`, indicating that a method should no longer be used but still exists for backwards compatibility, and `@SupressWarnings`, to prevent warnings from showing up in the compiler.

Note that it's actually possible to get annotations which are not included in the core Java libraries and to declare your own annotations.

Answer (score 4):

The @ symbol denotes Annotations. They provide information about a class, its field or method (above which they appear). They cannot perform operations. The compilers or special annotation processors use this information to make writing code less verbose.

In Java Persistence API you use them to map a Java class with database tables.

For example
@Table()
Used to map the particular Java class to the date base table.

@Entity
Represents that the class is an entity class.

Similarly you can use many annotations to map individual columns, generate ids, generate version, relationships etc.

Answer (score 1):

As some other suggests, it is Java's annotation. It helps the compiler to validate your code and to notify the programmer as well.

Very simple code example:

```
public class SomeClass {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SomeClass";
    }

    @Deprecated
    public void doSomeOperation() {
        // some operation...
    }
}
```

The annotation from `SomeClass#toString` which is `@Override` helps the compiler to determine that it is an overridden function from the implicit inheritance to the class `Object`.

While the annotation from `SomeClass#doSomeOperation` will warn the programmer that the function itself is deprecated already and should be avoided to use.

Answer (score -4):

The annotations are for the reader or compiler, not executable code.

Comment: This is not correct; annotations can be preserved in the compiled byte code, and can be read and used at runtime. Some frameworks such as the Spring Framework and Java EE use this a lot.