# What does @ do in Java?

Tags: java

I was looking at some Java code and I saw this:
`@Override`. I know what that means, but then I saw it again with a different word so I was wondering,  what does this (`@`) do in Java?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [in java what does the @ symbol mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31822020/in-java-what-does-the-symbol-mean)

Answer (score 1):

The @ `at` are annotations, you can check more details [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/annotations-in-java/).