# What does eta @ symbol mean in Java language?

Tags: java, syntax, symbols

I am watching a tutorial on Java and there is @ symbol. What does it mean? It looks so much like a comment /* */ or this one //
Maybe it is a tag?

[image]

[image]

Comment: that is how annotations are used

Comment: Thank you, I could not find it anywhere googling @ eta in Java

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/

Answer (score 1):

The @ symbol is a Java Annotation. What a Java annotation does, is that it adds a special attribute to the variable, method, class, interface, or other language elements.

Comment: I think because there is another question like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31822020/in-java-what-does-the-symbol-mean?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

The "@" symbol is called an Annotation. You can take a look at these links here and they'll give you some good info in them:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/annotations.html